# Difference between "anyone" and "everyone"

Tags: indefinite-pronouns

What's the difference between **'anyone'** and '**everyone'** in the following sentences? And especially in the first sentence, are they both correct?

I know the difference between **anyone** and **everyone**. I think in the following sentences, they are interchangeable.

> 1- I will back ***anyone/everyone*** who tries to fight this evil man.
>
> 2- ***Anyone/everyone*** who has given birth to a baby knows how painful it is.

Comment: What you think the difference is? They are not interchangeable, just like the adjectives any and every are not interchangeable.

Comment: Hello, I don't know in the first sentence what difference it makes. I think in the first sentence they both can be used but I have doubts. In the second sentence I am absolutely sure I can use either one. It will be helpful if you tell me what the difference between the two in the first sentence is. I know in some contexts they both can be used. I think the first sentence is one of those.

Comment: Anyone who goes to the movie will like it. Everyone who goes to the movie will like it. That should be in any basic bilingual dictionary. They are not interchangeable but both or either can be used.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you. I have found a similar sentence to yours telling the difference between "anyone" and "everyone". I know the difference.  That's why I told that in the second sentence they both can be used. But my question is, in the first sentence, can they both be used and what's the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second sentence, they are pretty well interchangeable.  In the first sentence, there is a slightly different shade of meaning, which might be increased by the surrounding context. For example:

> Someone must stop General Zod! I will back **anyone** who tries to fight this evil man.

Here, by using the singular **someone** and the singular **anyone**, I'm communicating my expectation that that there's going to be a **one-on-one** confrontation between the evil man and some singular hero.

By contrast:

> Hitler will soon move his forces into France. I will back **everyone** who tries to fight this evil man.

Here, by referencing **forces** made of many soldiers and using the collective **everyone**, I'm emphasizing that this is going to be a **many-to-many** confrontation between the evil man's armies and a collection of heroic soldiers (possibly from many countries) who will fight back.

Comment: +1 Love the General Zod example!

Comment: So *anyone* = *any* singular person, while *everyone* = *every* singular person.  Nice answer.  Good luck with Zod, though.  :)