# Difference between "He doesn't like anyone who drinks Coke." and "He doesn't like everyone who drinks Coke."

Tags: indefinite-pronouns

I thought that negation of each of them, "anyone"and "everyone", is different, compared to just "anyone"and "everyone".

Are both correct? Are they different?

> He doesn't like anyone who drinks Coke in that room.

> He doesn't like everyone who drinks Coke in that room.

How about other similar sentences?

> He doesn't like anyone in that room.

> He doesn't like everyone in that room.

Comment: **Everyone who** should go with a singular verb: *Everyone who* ***drinks...***  It might seem illogical, but *everyone* is considered singular.

Comment: Thank. I append the letter "s" to the verb.

Comment: You should start Coke with a capital C, since it is a proper noun.

Comment: Your questions are too broad to be answered.  Let us know the particular details of why you think one sentence is better than the other.  Additionally, do you mean *Everyone in that room that drinks Coke* or do you mean *Everyone that drinks Coke in that room*?  In the first situation you refer to a room full of people and further refer to a subset of them that drink Coke.  In the second situation you refer to all the people on Earth and further refer to a subset of them who go into that specific room to drink Coke.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "anyone" and "everyone"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/167849/difference-between-anyone-and-everyone)

Comment: But I thought that negation of each of them, "anyone"and "everyon", is different, compared to just "anyone"and "everyon".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using "everyone" as the object of a negated verb is tricky. The sentences

> He doesn't like anyone in that room

and

> He likes no one in that room

mean he dislikes them all.

> He doesn't like everyone in that room

implies that he likes one or more, but not all.

The way to get the same meaning from "everyone" as is intended by the first two sentences is to avoid negating a verb.

> He dislikes everyone in that room.

In short, beware using "everyone" after a negated verb.

Answer (score 1):

"He doesn't like anyone ...." is the normal and correct way to express this idea.

"He doesn't like everyone ..." is probably a mistake. It might mean "He doesn't like the group (but he likes the individuals?).  It is more likely to be a badly expressed attempt to say "He doesn't like anybody..."